# Hello. Im having trouble deploying a contract on ganache. Can someone please assist? Im using python with a Solidity abi and bytecode

Tags: blockchain

Here is a link to a screenshot of the code as i couldnt figure out the formatting.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTx52.png

---

and a shot of the error:

```css
(venv) PS C:\Users\usuario\pyblock> py
Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from deploy import *
>>> deploy_contract(7,10,os.environ['ADDRESS_1'],os.environ['PRIVATE_KEY_1']) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\usuario\pyblock\deploy.py", line 27, in deploy_contract
    deployment = guess_number.constructor(secret_number).buildTransaction(transaction_body)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\pyblock\venv\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\pyblock\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 684, in buildTransaction
    return fill_transaction_defaults(self.web3, built_transaction)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\pyblock\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\transactions.py", line 121, in fill_transaction_defaults
    default_val = default_getter(web3, transaction)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\pyblock\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\transactions.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    web3.eth.max_priority_fee + (2 * web3.eth.get_block('latest')['baseFeePerGas'])
  File "C:\Users\usuario\pyblock\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 549, in max_priority_fee
    return self._max_priority_fee()
  File "C:\Users\usuario\pyblock\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "C:\Users\usuario\pyblock\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "C:\Users\usuario\pyblock\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 171, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'message': 'Method eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas not supported.', 'code': -32000, 'data': {'stack': 'Error: Method eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas not supported.\n    at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\geth_api_double.js:70:16)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at GethDefaults.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\gethdefaults.js:15:12)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n  
  at SubscriptionSubprovider.FilterSubprovider.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\subproviders\\filters.js:89:7)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\subproviders\\subscriptions.js:137:49)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at DelayedBlockFilter.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\delayedblockfilter.js:31:3)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at RequestFunnel.handleRequest (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\subproviders\\requestfunnel.js:32:12)\n    at next (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:136:18)\n    at Web3ProviderEngine._handleAsync (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:123:3)\n    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\node_modules\\web3-provider-engine\\index.js:107:12)\n    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)\n    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)', 'name': 'Error'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your transaction_body you need to add gasPrice like so:

```
"gasPrice": web3_connection.eth.gas_price
```

This is due to EIP1559 changing, and web3.py updating for the change.